# Alter titles of account tabs containing views tabs

Tags: 7, views, theming, routes

I can easily alter titles in user account tabs from inside template.php like so

```
function custom_theme_menu_alter(&$items) {
          $items['user/%user/edit']['title'] = 'mytitle1';
          $items['user/%user/view']['title'] = 'mytitle2';
                }
```

The user menu contains also tabs created by views (as pages). The problem is that every time the view gets new data, the tabs change back. I need to flush cache in order to see altered titles. What can be done about this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the cache for view? If your view is not heavy you can disable cache for views.

Comment: hi, cache for views was not set up.